# Verification email gives API key expired on Android

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-authentication, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm using this code to send a verification email with a custom dynamicLinkDomain `links.myapp.com`.

```
final acs = ActionCodeSettings(
        url: 'https://myapp.com/finishLogin',
        handleCodeInApp: true,
        iOSBundleId: 'com.myapp.mobileApp',
        androidPackageName: 'com.myapp.mobileApp',
        androidInstallApp: true,
        androidMinimumVersion: '18',
        dynamicLinkDomain: 'links.myapp.com',
      );

      await SecureStorageService.to.postEmail(email);
      await FirebaseService.to.auth.sendSignInLinkToEmail(
        email: email,
        actionCodeSettings: acs,
      );
```

That dynamicLinkDomain is setup correctly because I am using it in my app both with Android and iOS. But when I click on the login link on an Android device (emulator or real) I always get a 400 API key expired error

[image: Screenshot 2021-03-25 at 19 03 23]

I tried

- to clean the project with `flutter clean`
- create a new API key without restriction

but I still get the error. It seems like a dynamic link problem, but I can't spot it. Does someone have an idea?

I can see that i have in the email is very different depending if I'm generating the email from iOS

```
https://links.myapp.com/?link=https://links.myapp..com/__/auth/action?apiKey%3DAIzaS...NedNY%26mode%3DsignIn%26oobCode%3DKI4NK...F4ao-7yw%26continueUrl%3Dhttps://myapp..com/finishLogin%26lang%3Den&ibi=com.myapp..mobileApp&ifl=https://links.myapp..com/__/auth/action?apiKey%3DAIza...tNedNY%26mode%3DsignIn%26oobCode%3DKI...-7yw%26continueUrl%3Dhttps://myapp..com/finishLogin%26lang%3Den
```

or Android

```
https://links.myapp.com/__/auth/action?apiKey=AIza...edNY&mode=signIn&oobCode=XQI...2pCw&continueUrl=https://myapp.com/finishLogin&lang=en
```

Is that normal?